# jhipster and Spring-data-jpa OneToMany collection not updated

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, ehcache, jhipster

i have a problem with jhipster and spring data jpa.
I have a classic JHipster JPA entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROCEEDINGSINSTANCE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName="proceedingsinstance")
public class ProceedingsInstance implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "proceedings_bpm_code")
    private Integer proceedingsBpmCode;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private DateTime startDate;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private AgencyProceedings agencyProceedings;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Outcome outcome;

    @ManyToOne
    private Status status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proceedingsInstance", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Activity> activitys = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proceedingsInstance", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<MyDocument> myDocuments = new HashSet<>();

    ... getters/setters...
}
```

And a service class like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProceedingsInstanceService {

    ...bean injection...

    public ProceedingsInstance createByAgencyProceedings(
            Long agencyProceedingsId) {
        AgencyProceedings agencyProceedings = agencyProceedingsRepository.findOne(agencyProceedingsId);
        if (agencyProceedings == null) {
            return null;
        }
        User user = userService.getUserWithAuthorities();

        ProceedingsInstance existingProceedingsInstance = proceedingsInstanceRepository.findOneByAgencyProceedingsIdAndUserIdAndStatusIdNot(agencyProceedingsId,
                user.getId(), STATUS_COMPLETED.getId());
        if (existingProceedingsInstance != null) {
            return existingProceedingsInstance;
        }
        agencyProceedings.getAgencyModules().size();
        ProceedingsInstance proceedingsInstance = proceedingsInstanceMapper.agencyProceedingsToProceedingsInstance(agencyProceedings);
        proceedingsInstance.setOutcome(OUTCOME_WAITING);
        proceedingsInstance.setStatus(STATUS_STARTED);
        proceedingsInstance.setStartDate(new DateTime());
        proceedingsInstance.setUser(user);
        proceedingsInstanceRepository.save(proceedingsInstance);
        proceedingsInstanceSearchRepository.save(proceedingsInstance);
        myDocumentRepository.save(proceedingsInstance.getMyDocuments());
        return proceedingsInstance;
    }

    public ProceedingsInstance saveFile(Long id) {
        return changeProceedingsInstanceStatus(id, STATUS_SAVED);
    }

    public ProceedingsInstance sendFile(Long id) throws JsonProcessingException, JMSException {
        ProceedingsInstance proceedingsInstance = changeProceedingsInstanceStatus(id, STATUS_SENDED);
        if (proceedingsInstance == null) {
            return null;
        }
        JmsPortalQueue jmsPortalQueue = jmsPortalQueueMapper.proceedingsInstanceToJmsPortalQueueIntegrazione(proceedingsInstance,
                userService.getUserWithAuthorities());
        jmsService.sendToPortalQueue(jmsPortalQueue);
        return proceedingsInstance;
    }

    private ProceedingsInstance changeProceedingsInstanceStatus(Long id, final Status status) {
        ProceedingsInstance proceedingsInstance = proceedingsInstanceRepository.findOne(id);
        if (proceedingsInstance == null) {
            return null;
        }

        proceedingsInstance.getActivitys().size();
        Set<Activity> activities = proceedingsInstance.getActivitys();
        Optional<Activity> activityOpt = activities.parallelStream()
                .filter(activity -> status.getCode().equals(activity.getStatus().getCode()) && activity.getEndDate() == null).findFirst();
        if (activityOpt.isPresent()) {
            return proceedingsInstance;
        }
        Optional<Activity> activityToCloseOpt = activities.parallelStream()
                .filter(activity -> !status.getCode().equals(activity.getStatus().getCode()) && activity.getEndDate() == null).findFirst();
        if (activityToCloseOpt.isPresent()) {
            Activity activityToClose = activityToCloseOpt.get();
            activityToClose.setEndDate(new DateTime());
            activityRepository.save(activityToClose);
        }

        Activity activity = new Activity();
        activity.setStatus(status);
        activity.setStartDate(new DateTime());
        activity.setProceedingsInstance(proceedingsInstance);
        activityRepository.save(activity);
        proceedingsInstance.setStatus(status);
        proceedingsInstanceRepository.save(proceedingsInstance);
        proceedingsInstanceSearchRepository.save(proceedingsInstance);
        return proceedingsInstance;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        OUTCOME_WAITING = outcomeRepository.findByCode(OUTCOME_CODE_WAITING);
        STATUS_STARTED = statusRepository.findByCode(STATUS_CODE_STARTED);
        STATUS_SAVED = statusRepository.findByCode(STATUS_CODE_SAVED);
        STATUS_SENDED = statusRepository.findByCode(STATUS_CODE_SENDED);
        STATUS_COMPLETED = statusRepository.findByCode(STATUS_CODE_COMPLETED);
    }

}
```

The methods are invoked by rest call for each one. The flow of execution is:

1. call createByAgencyProceedings method
2. after some time call saveFile

**The issue is**: if i call saveFile twice, **proceedingsInstance.getActivitys().size()** the second time is ZERO even if in the related table (ACTIVITY) the data is present with correct foreign key
Where am i wrong?

**Edit 1:**
I think the problem is related to the cache because after the changing the @Cache annotation in this way:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE)
```

The method *saveFile* works fine.
Can someone explain how can i update the cache?

Answer (score 0):

You should try set cascade on your relationship.

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
```

Comment: Nothing, the behavior is still the same. Thanks anyway.